# Dockerized spring boot app with multiple (dynamic) datasources

Tags: spring-boot, docker, containers, datasource, multi-tenant

I'm working on a Spring Boot application, using AbstractRoutingDatasource in order to provide multitenancy feature. New tenants can be added dynamically, and each one has it's own datasource and pool configuration, and everything is working well, since we only have around 10 tenants right now.

But I'm wondering: since the application is running on a docker container, with limit resources, as the number of tenants grows, also more and more threads will be allocated for each connection (considering a pool from 1 to 30 threads for each tenant) and the container, at some point (with 50 tenants, for example), will be killed due to memory limit defined at container startup.

It appears to me that, this multitenancy solution (using AbstractRoutingDatasource) is not suitable to an application designed to be containerized since I can't simply scale it horizontally to deal with more tenants.

Am I missing something? Should I be worried about that?

Comment: why not have services in containers and have them communicate with each other, the microservices way than having a huge monolith that will exhaust your resources and cause whole app to fail.

Comment: Thats not the point @Saravanan, this application is not a monolith. Instead it is composed by a few independent services (designed to be stateless), but every one of them needs to process requests from any client (tenant) and not from a single client (tenant).

Answer (score 0):

The point made in the post is about the system resource exhaustion that might arise with the increasing volume of requests as a result of increased tenants in the system. I would like to address few points

1. The whole infrastructure can be managed efficiently using `ECS & AWS Fargate` so that when there is a huge load, there are automatically new containers spun up to take the load. In case of having separate servers, `ELB` might be of help. There will be no issues when spinning up new containers / servers as your services are stateless
2. Regarding the number of active connections to a database from your application, you should profile your app and understand the `DAP` data access patterns. Any master data or static information should `NOT` be taken always from the database (Except for the 1st time), instead they should be cached. There are many managed cache services that can help you scale better.
3. In regards to the database, it is understood that tenants have their own databases, in case of a very large tenant, try to scale out the databases as well.
4. Focus on building the entire suite of features using `async` features in JAVA or using `RxJava` so that the async nature will help managing the threads.

Since you have not mentioned what cloud your applications will be deployed, I have cited sample using `AWS`. However most of the features can be used across `Azure` , `GCP` or `AWS`.

There are lot of strategies to scale, the right understanding of the business needs and data usage patterns etc... could help us decide the right approach.

Hope this clarifies.